# «Приму(,) как комплимент» — нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Нужна ли здесь запятая?

> Приму, как комплимент.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

— Вы примете мои извинения?
— Приму, как обычно. (Один человек вредит другому, но извиняется, а другой постоянно принимает извинения и не злится на обидчика.)

— Вы примете мои извинения?
— Приму как обычно. (Один человек вредит другому, но тот формально принимает извинения, но затаивает обиду и как-то вредит обидчику.)

В вашем предложении может быть только один вариант: «Приму как комплимент». Сочетание «как комплимент» образует словосочетание с «приму» и характеризует это самое принятие.

Comment: Авторская грамматика от Jim Korbett,  новое понимание терминов.  А вот «устаревшее» определение: « Синтаксически неделимые словосочетание - это словосочетания, в которых главное и зависимое слово сливаются по смыслу и выступают как единый член предложения. К таким словосочетаниям относятся: https://studopedia.su/13_118660_sintaksicheski-nedelimie-slovosochetaniya.html  Не там ничего похожего на «принять как комплимент», да и у Розенталя такой информации тоже нет. Читайте литературу, а свои грамматические фантазии дополняйте ссылками на источники, как это принято на форуме.

Comment: Приводите два интонационных варианта. Действительно, их именно два. А потом этой структуре можно придать разное лексическое наполнение в зависимости от речевой ситуации. Понятно выражаюсь?

Comment: Отчего же "только один вариант"? 1. - Вы примете высказанное о вас мнение? - Приму, как комплимент. 2. - А если вас назовут иноагентом? - Приму как комплимент.

Comment: @Alex_ander, вы привели два примера, где «приму как комплимент» имеют одинаковый смысл — «как комплимент» характеризует принятие, комплиментарное принятие, если можно так сказать.

Comment: @Sharon Если бы справочник Розенталя был качественным — отчетливо сформулирован каждый пункт, темы грамотно сегментированы и сгруппированы, темы описаны всеобъемлюще, — то на форуме не было бы сегмента про пунктуацию вообще. 
Если вы имеете ввиду необусловленную синтаксисом паузу, то нет смысла об этом писать, потому что она обозначает заминки, умолкания, заикания и может ставится абсолютно везде. Приму... как комплимент. 
Я не имел ввиду термин «синтаксически неделимые», то есть являющиеся одним членом предложения.

Comment: У Розенталя также нет информации про ваше конфу, в котором есть некое «тоническое ударение»(сам Господь не знает что это).

Comment: @Jim Korbett  Господь уж точно знает, а  еще в справочниках по вузовской фонетике можно почитать (если просветиться наконец захотели и духовно вырасти). А вы, смотрю, на "минусовочках" тренируетесь. А я вот вам ни одного минуса не поставила (я минусов не ставлю, все об этом знают).  А сколько плюсов - и не счесть!  Нечестный прием в дискуссии, не думала, что вы до такого опуститесь..

Comment: Вы не имели ввиду термин «синтаксически неделимые», то есть являющиеся одним членом предложения.? А что же вы тогда имели в виду, неужели «лексически неделимые» словосочетания?  Тогда это еще хуже! Фразеологическими сращениями называются такие лексически неделимые словосочетания, значение которых не определяется значением входящих в них отдельных слов. Например:  из рук вон - «плохо», трусу (или труса) праздновать - «бояться, опасаться» и т.д.  Кстати, по Лопатину эти обороты входят в состав сказуемого (один член предложения). Читайте справочники, прежде чем отвечать

Comment: И правка ответа неудачная: предложение  вообще строится на основе различных словосочетаний, эти грамматические связи сохраняются и в предложении. Правьте дальше. Подставляетесь под критику, однако.

Comment: Я имел ввиду просто словосочетания. Например, в первом предложении «приму, как обычно» не является словосочетанием, а во втором «приму как обычно» является словосочетаниям.

Answer (score 3):

***Приму как комплимЕнт.***

1. Да,  скорее всего, здесь оборот имеет значение «в качестве», как уже было сказано, то есть **нет паузы** и нет обособления (интонация простого предложения).
2. Правда,  доверяю я исключительно **Розенталю или ПАС под ред. Лопатина.** Изучать тему можно по любым материалам, но для ссылки лучше пользоваться официальным источником, а не его пересказом.

Розенталь, п. 4.3.http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Пункт 4.3.  Сравнительный оборот с союзом как **не выделяется** запятыми:  3) если союз как имеет значение **‘в качестве’** или сравнительный оборот с союзом как характеризует предмет лишь **с одной стороны:** Богат, хорош собою, Ленский везде был принят как жених (П.); Итак, я вам советую как приятель быть осторожнее (Л.); Я говорю как литератор (М. Г.); Мы знаем Индию как страну древнейшей культуры; Я сохраню это письмо как память; Они разговаривают как чужие; Мы встретились как старые знакомые; Покупается и продаётся как товар не труд, а рабочая сила; Исследователи космоса остановились на собаках как достаточно высокоорганизованных животных; Переговоры с ним надлежало вести как с равной стороной; Пётр I не считал для себя зазорным работать как простой плотник; Юрий Гагарин вошёл в историю как первый в мире космонавт, [См. § 19, п. 7.]

ПАС под редакцией Лопатина http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125

§ 90. Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что не выделяются запятыми в следующих случаях: б) при передаче **значения «в качестве»** (оборот является частью сказуемого):
Сергей Лазо был прислан комитетом как главнокомандующий (Фад.); ...Тамара Ивановна поняла этот голос как посланное ей вдогонку прощание (Расп.);

3. А вот интересно, **возможно ли обособление оборота** в этом предложении?

Можно придумать такой диалог:

– *Примите мои слова как извинение.*

– *ПримУ, как комплимЕнт.*

Здесь значение такое: приму, но (приму) как комплимент.  При отсутствии противительного союза в неполном предложении делается пауза, оборот обособляется.

Comment: В вопросе нет контекста, а также нет ни противительного союза "но", ни глагола "приму" повторно. А смысл, который Вы указываете, конечно же, _теоретически_ возможен. Но тогда в предложении (в отсутствие союза и глагола) для обозначения паузы потребуется уже не запятая, а тире: **Приму — как комплимент**. –

Comment: Если вам потребуется, то вы и ставьте, я разве возражаю. Мне же запятой вполне достаточно, она тоже паузу обозначает. К тому же вы только паузы слышите, а там еще дополнительно тоническое ударение ставится (хорошо, кстати, фиксируется  на слух). А рассматриваю нестандартный синтаксис, а вы мне под него  стандартные рамочки и правила подбираете.

Comment: Смысл остается таким же: «как комплимент» характеризует принятие. Но если вы произносите это с умолканием, то здесь ставится многоточие, так как многоточие обозначает необусловленную синтаксисом паузу. Приму... как комплимент. Но этот пример очень глупый, так как такая пауза может ставится абсолютно-абсолютно везде. В любом предложении в речи человек может умолкать на время, заикаться и тп.

Comment: Крайне несправедливо удалены самые важные комментарии. О том, что это правило: «При отсутствии противительного союза в неполном предложении делается пауза, оборот обособляется» — было придумано автором ответа на ходу; о том, что никто никогда не воспримет предложение: «Приму, как комплимент», как «Приму, но как комплимент», и тут придумано не просто одно правило, а еще то, как люди будут воспринимать смысл предложения, несмотря на то, что это не следует из каких-либо слов и знаков.

Comment: У предложения может быть такой смысл: «Приму...(человек кратко задумывается и корректирует ответ) как комплимент». Поскольку краткая пауза для размышления является необусловленной синтаксисом паузой, то здесь ставится многоточие. Но опять же, такая пауза может ставится везде.

Comment: Jim Korbett, мы все друг другу уже сказали, по крайней мере на ближайшее время. Вы от меня отдохнули? А я от вас еще нет.

Answer (score 2):

Второй ответ (после комментариев)

**О грамматике, интонации, структурно-интонационных схемах и их лексическом наполнении**

1. Всё-таки **дискуссия** – это отличная вещь для «духовного» роста (я себя имею в виду),  жаль, что у нас мало дискуссий. Мои оппоненты подсказывают мне **новые решения**, новый взгляд на обычные вещи. Вот я много занималась конкретными структурно-интонационными схемами/моделями, пора их как-то **обобщить**.
2. Берем повествовательное предложение из двух слов. Можно его разделить на две части? Почему же нет – легко! Мне видятся **4 основные схемы:** (1) запятая,  (2) тире присоединительное, (3) тире разделительное,  (4) двоеточие.

Они различают по движению тона в первой части (понижение или повышение) и длительности пауз (максимальная для двоеточия, минимальная для запятой, средняя для тире). Повышение тона делается только для разделительного тире, в остальных случаях тон понижается (правда, у двоеточия неполное понижение). **Вот и вся премудрость.** Теоретически  (без конкретного лексического наполнения) можно взять любую схему.

**3. Что делает** Jim Korbett? Он берет схему с запятой и доказывает, что она **существует** с помощью оборота «как обычно». Доказал – да, существует. Но потом утверждает следующее: «принять как комплимент» – «неразделимое» сочетание (ну просто как атом неделимый в классической физике).

4. Но я-то привела пример  **нестандартной речевой ситуации,** когда сочетание делится, причем в качестве дополнительного материала к основному ответу. И тут же **окрик с двух сторон – нельзя!** Вот бы здесь нашему Джиму пофантазировать и придумать еще какие-нибудь ситуации, но он фантазирует только в области общепринятой  грамматической терминологии.
5. А что предлагает нам Римма Михайлова?   Только чисто **теоретически** можно разделить (тоже хорошая мысль, возьму на заметку), но с помощью **тире,** а не запятой, а то **пауза не обозначена**.  Почему она не обозначена, какое именно тире (присоединительное или разделительное)?  Здесь уж, как говорится, без комментариев.
6. А что говорит Alex_ander ?  Он тоже говорит **о возможности**  структурных схем с разделением, но на примере другого лексического наполнения. Кстати, именно этот комментарий **направил меня к мысли** о необходимости обобщения схем, за что ему отдельное спасибо.

Ну и всем остальным участникам дискуссии  спасибо тоже. **Искреннее спасибо**, без иронии.

Comment: И вам, _Sharon_, искреннее спасибо (решайте сами — с иронией или без).  Вы исказили мои слова. Я говорила о том, что "смысл, который Вы указываете, конечно же, теоретически возможен".  Я помню своё бескрылое и безфантазийное место — Вы мне его откровенно указали. И я бесхитростно и приземленно рада, что в последнее время на сайте присутствуют только два мнения: Ваше и неправильное. Вы своими псевдодискуссиями и переходами на личность отбиваете всякое желание отвечать. А потом удивляетесь: почему же форум стал малоактивным?

Comment: Римма, я понимаю, что вы огорчены, извините меня. Право же, не стоит, по своему печальному опыту это знаю. Мир по большому счету равнодушен к нашим эмоциям. А если вся жизнь театр, так пусть в нем будет больше смеха, чем драматических историй, тогда чувствуешь себя сильней и увереннее.   «Злодеев нет вовсе на свете, мы все простодушны, как дети. Задиры и врушки, мы делим игрушки…» А я вчера в парке видела сороку и про вас вспомнила – интересно есть ли у вас сороки. Весна же, май! Улыбнитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: Наши сороки — лоснящиеся. удивительно яркие, супер-пупер длиннохвостые. И лисы по городу шастают. Бывает, пробегают зайцы и еноты, и кабанчик недавно по кордону шнырял. Пару недель назад видела черного дятла — он блестящий и громкий. Оживленный симбиоз леса, реки и моря — это удивительное зрелище! Большие носатые белые чайки топчутся по зелени, а вороны фланируют по песчаному побережью. Как тут не улыбнуться?

Comment: Класс, вот чему позавидовать можно! И знаете, стиль письма у вас прекрасный – лексика и грамматика просто безупречные. А какая образность, эмоциональность, выразительность – ваши птички и лисы как будто живые. Неужели вы ничего не пишете? Если так, то это неправильно. Мы всего этого не видим, а вы нам хотя бы рассказали про такую красоту. Жаль, что на этой платформе нет творческого раздела, вы бы имели большой успех. Можно на https://proza.ru публиковаться, там бы вас тоже оценили. Если не хотите под собственным именем, то псевдоним можно взять. А я вам буду писать рецензии, договорились?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на комментарий

Римма, как бы вы ни ругали меня, я все равно благодарна вам и всем другим участникам за то, что с вашей помощью я **получаю здесь новые знания**. В последней дискуссии я рассказала, как я это делаю, не более того. И слово  «теоретически» мне тоже пригодилось – кто-то мне должен был его подсказать.  Знаете, это закон жизнь – так необходимую  информацию мы иногда получаем совершенно случайным образом.

**Псевдодискусии, но почему же**? Вот, например,  вопрос  о структурно-интонационной классификации.  В Грамматике-80 уже давалась классификация предложений по виду (структурная грамматика и  приложенный к ней образец лексического наполнения),  но почему-то это направление не получило активного развития, а мне эта мысль нравится. Единый знак? Я о нем много думала, но только после вашего вопроса поняла: нужно составить хотя бы версию его значения и области применения.  И это результаты только  двух дискуссий, неужели не видно, что я искренне благодарна и вам, и другим.

И своего мнения я никому не навязываю – единственное, что мене очень не по душе, то это **искажение грамматики**. Серьезная наука – ею занимаются знающие люди, нам там делать нечего.  Поэтому  грамматические фантазии некоторых участников мне кажутся недопустимыми – иначе мы будем вводить людей в заблуждение, а ведь они доверяют нам. Здесь я оставляю за собой право на критику.

Я сначала отвечаю на вопросы, используя **только классику**, стороной обходя непроверенные учебные сайты (давать на них ссылки не стоит). И только потом могу привести  какой-то дополнительный материал, как это было в этом (таком резонансном) вопросе. Но почему-то  именно это дополнение вызвало столько нелестных отзывов.

**Форум есть форум**, здесь нет ни детей ни взрослых, все одинаковые, так что и скидок для нас тоже нет (как их нет и в жизни). Каждый имеет право говорить то, что считает нужным.  А чье мнение присутствует на сайте – это от многого зависит. Здесь можно услышать такое суждение: если хотите быть в центре внимания, то будьте там.

**Конструктивную критику** я всегда приветствую, но только в цивилизованной форме –  пусть критикуют не меня, а мои взгляды.  И так, чтобы всем от этого была польза, чтобы был у людей живой интерес к дискуссиям, чтобы все участвовали в нем. Разные мнения, противоположные суждения – разе это не интересно?

А вот на личности я **стараюсь не переходить** из осторожности – запрещено правилами.  Внимательно слежу за всем сказанным, как бы включаю внутренний «модератор».   Форум хорошо меня «воспитал», очень старался – ни плакать, ни искать сочувствия и понимания здесь не стоит. Ничего личного, как говорится.